# Script to automatically eject Windows and System reserved NTFS volumes upon logging in to OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-lion

Basically I need a script that would upon logging into OSX Lion eject Windows and system reserved NTFS volumes that show up in finder or just entirely eject the SSD that they are on.

I don't have much experience with scripting for OSX and would not even know where to put the script for it to startup upon logging in.

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "Finder" to eject disk "nameOfSSD"
```

Save this script as an application file somewhere.

#### To run the script upon login...

1. Open up System Preferences
2. Navigate to the "Accounts" pane
3. Click on your username in the pane at the left
4. Click "Login Items" at the top of the window
5. Click the + sign at the bottom.
6. Find your script in the file browser that comes up; click "Choose"/"Ok" when you've found the script.
7. Close System Preferences

Just restart your computer to see the script in action. :)

Comment: Uhh and what exactly is the script to: tell application "Finder" to eject disk "nameOfSSD" ? Should this script autogenerate somewhere if I do it through the GUI ? What is the script extension to save with ? I presume "tell application "Finder" to eject disk "nameOfSSD" is not the actual script?

Comment: @LaserBeak If you're trying to eject the `Macintosh HD` drive, you can't. An equivilent of this would be to log the user out: `tell application "System Events" to log out`. You save the script as an `Application` so it actually runs the script.